# Why KeyDown is not working on my control, but on the whole form?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keyboard, keydown

I am using this routine to check if my `LeftCtrl` key is pressed on my Image control:

```
private void mainImage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        LeftCtrlButtonIsPressed = true;
    }
}

private void mainImage_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        LeftCtrlButtonIsPressed = false;
    }
}
```

When I set my events **on Image or the Border** around my Image it **does not Hit**:

```
<Border x:Name="mainImageBackBorder" .... KeyDown="mainImage_KeyDown" KeyUp="mainImage_KeyUp"> <! -- Does not Hit -->
    <Image x:Name="mainImage" ... KeyDown="mainImage_KeyDown" KeyUp="mainImage_KeyUp"> <! -- Does not Hit -->
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <! -- ... -->
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Border>
```

However, it **Hit**s when I set it **on my Window**:

```
<Window x:Class="ProjectName.MainWindow"
        ..
        DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel }"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" KeyDown="mainImage_KeyDown" KeyUp="mainImage_KeyUp"> <!-- It Hits -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image control will not receive KeyDown events because the [Focusable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) property is set to false by default. From the first line of the Focusable documentation:

> Only the focused element receives keyboard input.

Also worth noting:

> When deriving from UIElement directly (as opposed to from Control),
>   consider whether you wish your element to be focusable, because by
>   default the element will not be focusable. If you wish your element to
>   be focusable, override the metadata for this property within your
>   type's static constructor as follows:

As you can see from the [Image class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) it derives from UIElement, not Control, so by default it cannot receive the focus.

This should work correctly if you make the Image focusable, but keep in mind the obvious side effect - your user's current focus can be lost on an Image control which has no visual indication that it is selected.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping :) I will be aware of this in the future